# How to represent $set1=\{a b, a c\}$ as $set2=\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}\}$?

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, output-formatting, formatting

I need representation $set1=\{a b, a c\}$ as $set2=\{\{a, b\}, \{a, c\}\}$

```
set1={a b, a c}
```

Note I have seen some questions and found the opposite direction

```
Times@@@set2=set1
```

if it was `set1={a,a b, a c,d}={a,{a, b}, {a, c},d}`
  When the process `/. Times -> List`, but I need `set1={a,a b, a c,d}={{a},{a, b}, {a, c},{d}}` 
How??
Regards,

Comment: Find the gcd of the two elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A straightforward approach is to use replacement rules:

```
set1 = {a b, a c};
set1 /. Times -> List
{{a, b}, {a, c}}
```

You can figure this kind of thing out by looking at the FullForm:

```
FullForm[set1]
List[Times[a,b],Times[a,c]]
```

So what needs to be changed is that the head Times should change into the head List.

To handle the revised question, use a similar process, only now you
have to control which level the mapping is done, so we add the requested brackets and then perform the appropriate replacement:

```
set1 = {a, a b, a c, d};
Replace[set1, x_ -> {x}, 1] /. List[Times[x_, y_]] -> List[x, y]
{{a}, {a, b}, {a, c}, {d}}
```

Comment: If set1 = {a,a b, a c}={{a},{a, b}, {a, c}}

Comment: equivalently `List @@ # & /@ set1`

Comment: @bills Is this   set1 = {a,a b, a c}={{a},{a, b}, {a, c}} possible?

Comment: See update for a solution.

Comment: Thanks.........

Comment: An alternative that might be useful for you is `Sequence`, which you could use like `Map[List, set1] /. Times -> Sequence`

Answer (score 1):

with the new definition of set:

```
set1={a,a b, a c,d}

Composition[  Flatten , List, List @@ # &] /@ set1
```

output:

> {{a},{a,b},{a,c},{d}}

Comment: if `set1={Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2] Subscript[x, 3]}`  The result is not correct.

Comment: I get this `{{x, 1}, {Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3]}}`

Comment: why dont you just ask the final question instead of changing it everytime?

Comment: I gave a simple example but when you take different examples show problems

Comment: try `Composition[List, List@# &] /@ set1 ` or it has to work in both cases? btw bill solution works in both cases

Comment: `Composition[Flatten, List@# &] /@ set1` work in both cases